# Sphinx in C++ (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, python-sphinx

This time I want to implement **Sphinx** in **Linux**. Please give me the **API** required to do the same or the concerned link will also do. Although I found many for PHP, however none for C++.

I have also used GTKmm in my application.

Comment: Are you talking about "Sphinx" the documentation generator or "CMU Sphinx" the Open Source Toolkit For Speech Recognition ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API to do this. Sphinx will process text files in reStructuredText format and turn them into documentation. The ability to extract documentation from source code is only present for python code. For other languages you will need to put the documentation in the reStructuredText files directly. Do not be confused by the added C/C++/etc. support in Sphinx 1.0: this only covers new reStructeredText directives to better format (and index) documentation regarding non-python code.

It is theoretically possible to use a tool like Doxygen to extract documentation from C++ sources and use that in Sphinx, but this requires custom tools. [Breathe](http://michaeljones.github.com/breathe/index.html) may be one such tool.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the resource that pretty much explains everything step-by-step that is needed to build a C/C++ source tree to show up with Sphinx documentation.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clear-functional-c-documentation-with-sphinx-breathe-doxygen-cmake/

A brief of the pipeline: Doxygen -> Breathe -> Exhale -> Sphinx